# Transformers for non-NLP tasks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm looking into using Transformer model for non-NLP generative tasks. Specifically,

1. Events in a sequence semantically happen at the same time unordered;
2. Events are in high-dimensional vectors that cannot be tokenized naively as in most NLP applications. The same for targets.

(1) seems to break the basic assumption of `Positional Encoding`; (2) seems to break most of the implementations, and although I can change the lead-in and lead-out of the model I'm not sure whether the decoding layer will handle this correctly in practice.

Do any of my concern stand? Are Transformers for my task?

Comment: see "image transformer"

Comment: Thank you @shimao ! I read that paper and it seems that it's still a bit off - Images have spacial dependencies that make elements having some orders (two pixels can not be at the same position). Do you have any other examples that deal with unordered data?